# apollo-server-plugin-response-cache: How to invalid cache?

Tags: apollo

I'm using the apollo-server-plugin-response-cache package, set up in the server creation like this

```
const responseCachePlugin = require('apollo-server-plugin-response-cache');
const server = new ApolloServer({
  // ...
  plugins: [responseCachePlugin()],
});
```

However I can't find in the documentation how to delete or update a value from the cache when an event occurs, like a mutation query. How can this be achieved inside the GraphQL resolver responsible for this?

Comment: very relevant, also looking for an answer

Comment: According to the following Github issue: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/pull/2437#issuecomment-575395081 - there is no support for cache invalidation yet.